# how to register events for ajax returned html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery so I don't know if I have titled the question correctly. For post back html marks, I can register events for the  like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
 ...});
```

now I need to allow user to click a button to add more items by triggering an ajax call and append the server response that contains the marks for the new item :

```
$(this).click(function(){
     $.get("my url", {}, function (data) {$("#xxx").append(data);});
     });
```

My question is: now there are some new marks with attribute [data-autocomplete] within returned "data",how can I do the same events registration for them? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you registering any events on your code, but it looks like you want to initialize a plugin on each match. Please clarify?

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, I want to initalize auto-complete featuer for the input within the ajax returned content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ***on*** to delegate events: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click", ":input[data-autocomplete]", function(event){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this:the appending content including some new input ,you need to register events after appending them as following?

```
$(this).click(function(){
    $.get("my url", {}, function (data) {
        $("#xxx").append(data);
        $("#xxx").find(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
        ...});
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 but he doesn't need to do it everytime he recieves an object with that attribute.For more efficient handling @daeshanagas answer is more suitable. You can refer to the invoking element using this